# A Curious Binomial Coefficient Sum: $\sum_{j = 0}^{k} \binom{k}{j} \binom{j + n -\ell + 1}{n}$

Tags: summation, special-functions, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Let $k, \ell \leq n$ be non-negative integers. Does the following identity simplify?
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^{k}  \binom{k}{j}     \binom{j + n -\ell + 1}{n} = \binom{n - \ell + 1}{n} \phantom1_{2}\mathsf{F}_{1}(-k,n - \ell + 2, 2- \ell; -1)
\end{align}
where $\!\!\! \phantom1_{2}\mathsf{F}_{1}$ is a [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html). That is, does the right side have another representation in terms of simple functions given that $k,\ell$ and $n$ are non-negative integers?

Comment: $\binom{n-l+1}{n}=0$ if $l > 1$ I guess

Comment: Superficially it appears that the right side vanishes, but you must also consider the hypergeometric function. The sum is equal to $2^{k-1} k$ if $l = 2$ and $n = 1$.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "simple function"? The theory behind Gosper's algorithm will tell you that if the sum exists as a hypergeometric then it's a rational polynomial times the summand.

Comment: Following @GEdgar's comment: how do you define $\binom{a}{b}$ when $a < b$ -- not as $0$?

Comment: Are you interested in simplifying the left hand side?  At least in a formal form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us denote:
\begin{equation}
S_k^{n,l} := \sum\limits_{j=0}^k 
\left( \begin{array}{c} k \\ j \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c} n-l+1+j \\ n \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_k^{n,l} &:=&  \left. \frac{d^n}{n! d x^n} x^{n-l+1} \cdot \left(1+x\right)^k \right|_{x=1} \\ 
&=& 
\frac{1}{n!} \sum\limits_{p=0}^n
\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ p \end{array} \right) (n-l+1)_{(p)} k_{(n-p)} 2^{k-n+p} \\
&=&2^{k-n} 
\left( \begin{array}{c} k \\ n \end{array} \right) {}_2F_1\left[4-n,-n,1+k-n;2\right]
\end{eqnarray}

The last result, that in terms of the hypergeometric function is not particularily useful when $n$, $l$, $k$ are integers. However the result above is useful for example if $k$ is large.